# How to connect an embedded device to Internet via a Windows 7 PC's Shared Internet Connection (ICS)?

Tags: linux, windows, networking, modem, internet-connection

I have an embedded device (runs linux) that is connected to my Windows 7 workstation via ethernet. My Windows 7 computer is connected to the internet via usb modem (ppp protocol).

Can I connect my device to the internet somehow without connecting the modem directly to the device? Thanks for helpers!

Comment: It's not likely

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If i understand your question or issue correctly:

**Yes, definetly** . You could set up your workstation to act as the network gateway for the device. That way your device could access the internet trough the *shared modem connection* of your workstation.

It's a bit hard to give more details than that without knowing the operating system of your workstation. But most modern operating systems have made sharing internet connections relatively easy.

EDIT: You mention you're using Windows 7, so the steps should be fairly easy. The following steps should work for ethernet, wifi and dial-up connections.

1. Choose **Start→Control Panel→Network and Internet**. Click the **Network and Sharing Center** link.
2. In the resulting **Network and Sharing Center** window, click the **Manage (Wireless) Network**'s link.
3. *Click a connection and then click the **Adapter Properties** link.*
4. Click the **Sharing** tab.
5. Select the **Allow Other Network Users to Connect through This Computer’s Internet Connection** check box.
6. Click OK and then close the Manage (Wireless) Networks window to save the shared connection settings.
7. Set the IP of the workstation your device is connected to as the gateway/DHCP in the devices network settings.

(from : http://www.dummies.com/computers/operating-systems/windows-7/how-to-share-an-internet-connection-in-windows-7/ )

Comment: I am using windows 7

Comment: @Shlomi check out e.g http://www.dummies.com/computers/operating-systems/windows-7/how-to-share-an-internet-connection-in-windows-7/

Comment: that means that I need to enable sharing and change the default gateway of my device to my computer's IP?

Comment: @Shlomi From what i can remember (i have not used Windows since Vista); But, yes. It should be as simple as that i think. Also google "Windows Internet Connection Sharing" or more specifically "Windows Internet Connection Sharing ICS" for more details.

Comment: Thanks! I will try!

Comment: @Shlomi for more about ICS https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Connection_Sharing